# Detekt task fails only if ran without check task

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, detekt

I'm migrating detekt from 1.0.0.RC7-2 to the 1.0.1 and changing to use the new plugin syntax. I managed to make it work, but only when the full check task is executed.

If only the detekt task is executed then an error is shown.

**The detekt task is failing with the following error:**

```
Task :detekt FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':detekt'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detekt'.
Cannot resolve external dependency io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-cli:1.0.1 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
     project :
```

**detekt.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt'

detekt {
    config = files("$rootDir/detekt/detekt-ruleset.yml")
    filters = ".*build.*,.*/resources/.*,.*/tmp/.*"
    input = files("src/main/java", "src/test/java")
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = false
        txt.enabled = false
    }
}
```

**build.gradle** (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:1.0.1"
    }
}

plugins {
     id "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt" version "1.0.1"
}
```

**build.gradle** (module):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

apply from: "$rootDir/detekt/detekt.gradle"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work by creating a task for Detekt and not using the plugin:

**detekt.gradle**

```
configurations {
    detekt
 }

dependencies {
    detekt "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-cli:1.0.1"
}

task detekt(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.cli.Main"
    classpath = configurations.detekt
    def input = "$rootDir"
    def config = "$rootDir/detekt/detekt-ruleset.yml"
    def exclude = ".*/resources/.*,.*/build/.*"
    def report = "html:${project.buildDir}/reports/detekt.html"
    def params = ['-i', input, '-c', config, '-ex', exclude, '-r', report]
    args(params)
}

check.dependsOn detekt
```

**build.gradle** (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:1.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/issues/713) filed on detekt repo, you have to configure it on the root project, not on the app module.

Comment: And how do I do that? The post doesn't have an example of the right way to do it

Comment: Link no longer available

Comment: This idea helped me despite the fair points above